# How to find words count in a text file excluding one user given word

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have the large set of the text file. In that, each article is separated by `15 stopwords`. I want to find out the total number of words count in that file excluding the `stopword`

Comment: try this: `sed 's/stopword//g' file | wc -w`

Comment: seems like a reasonable Answer to me, @taliezin!

Comment: It would help (for accurate answers) to see what your input looks like— a small representative sample.

Comment: What defines a word?

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '\S+' < file | grep -vcxF stopword
```

Would count (`-c`) the number of words (with the same definition of *word* as that of `wc -w`, at least on valid text, that is sequences of non-spacing characters (`\S+`)) that are not (`-v`) exactly (`-xF`) `stopword`.

Comment: `grep ... < file`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756), one could also do `{ grep ... | grep ...; } < file` to avoid the `0` if the file can't be opened.

Answer (score 3):

The number of words in `input` minus the number of `stopword`s (using [GNU grep's `-o`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), since you tagged Linux):

```
echo $(( $(wc -w < input) - $( grep -o stopword input | wc -l ) ))
```

Sample input:

```
I have the large set of the text file. In that, each article is separated by 15 stopwords. I want to find out the total number of words count in that file excluding the stopword.
stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword stopword
I have the large set of the text file. In that, each article is separated by 15 stopwords. I want to find out the total number of words count in that file excluding the stopword.
```

Output:

```
$ echo $(( $(wc -w < input) - $( grep -o stopword input | wc -l ) ))
66
```

Comment: Note that on an input like `stopwordstopword-stopword`, that would give `-2`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ gsub("stopword",""); words+=NF }; END { print words; }' /text/file
```

This counts everything that `awk` considers a field. Even it is semantically not a word like

- a hyphen
- a dot after a space (wrong end of sentence . Next sentence)
- numbers in headings ( 1. introduction )